# How to make a bicolor table board in Java

Tags: java, swing

In my Java class we are working in chapter 4 of the Fundamentals of Java book. I'm doing project 4-11 which is a black and red checkerboard however I'm getting random colors, I'm trying to complete this the way the book teaches us to use ColorPanels and JFrames. Here is my code:

```
package guiwindow3;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GUIWindow3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Objects
        JFrame theGUI = new JFrame();

        //Format GUI
        theGUI.setTitle("GUI Example");

        theGUI.setSize(500, 500);
        theGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container pane = theGUI.getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));

        //Loop for grid
        Color lastColor = Color.BLACK;

        for(int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {

            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {

                if((j % 2 == 1 && i %2 == 1) || (j % 2 == 0 && i % 2 == 0)) {

                    lastColor = Color.RED;

                }

                else {

                    lastColor = Color.BLACK;

                }

                ColorPanel panel = new ColorPanel(lastColor);

                pane.add(panel);

            }

        }

        theGUI.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Then for the ColorPanel class I have:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class ColorPanel extends JPanel {

    public ColorPanel(Color lastColor) {

        setBackground(lastColor);

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: It doesn't show the checkerboard

Comment: It works for me when I test it.

Comment: `if ((j % 2 == 1 && i %2 == 1) || (j % 2 == 0 && i % 2 == 0))` is the same as `if (j % 2 == i % 2)`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're getting random numbers is because you're creating a random number for each RGB parameter. Instead you could change this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= rows * cols; i++) {
    int red = gen.nextInt(256); //A random Red 
    int green = gen.nextInt(256); //A random Green
    int blue = gen.nextInt(256); //A random Blue
    Color backColor = new Color(red, green, blue); //Join them and you get a random color
    ColorPanel panel = new ColorPanel(backColor); //Paint the panel
    pane.add(panel);
}
```

To this:

```
Color lastColor = Color.BLACK;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        if ((j % 2 == 1 && i % 2 == 1) || (j % 2 == 0 && i % 2 == 0)) {
            lastColor = Color.RED; //Set the color to RED
        } else {
            lastColor = Color.BLACK; //Set the color to BLACK
        }
        ColorPanel panel = new ColorPanel(lastColor); //Paint the panel with RED or BLACK color
        pane.add(panel); //Add the painted Panel
    }
}
```

And the output is something like:

[image]

---

**Edit**

Another way to get the same output and make the `if` condition easier to read, is as @dimo414 said in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160393/how-to-make-a-bicolor-table-board-in-java#comment56071379_34160393):

> `if((j % 2 == 1 && i %2 == 1) || (j % 2 == 0 && i % 2 == 0))` is the same as `if (j % 2 == i % 2)`

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        if (i % 2 == j % 2) {
            lastColor = Color.RED;
        } else {
            lastColor = Color.BLACK;
        }
        ColorPanel panel = new ColorPanel(lastColor);
        pane.add(panel);
    }
}
```

Comment: [This is what I get as output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7trak3pcs2yh7nz/Screenshot%202015-12-08%2012.23.30.png?dl=0)

Comment: @Dogrules23 Could you edit your post with the new code? And add your images here?

Comment: It won't let me embed the picture so it made it a link.

Comment: @Dogrules23 Check my code again, first `for-loop` goes from `i = 0; i < 8; i++` instead of `i = 1; i < 8; i++`. i.e. It starts on **0** not on **1**. And the link is fine, we can edit it for you so your image appears :)

Comment: That literally made all the difference! I didn't see that! Thanks!

Comment: @Dogrules23 If this answer solved your question please [Accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)